# Given an m-x-n matrix where m!=n, it must be true that dim( NullSpace(A)) != dim(NullSpace(A-transpose)) / T or F?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I think the answer to the question in the subject line is TRUE. But I wanted to confirm this with folks with more skills than I have. My reasoning is:

Say we have a matrix A,where

```
    A =   a d
          b e
          c f

    # rows = m=3,  # cols = n = 2
```

and suppose that the Rank(A) = 1 (2nd column is a multiple of first column).

My understanding so far is that:

```
    For any matrix A,  Rank(A) = Rank(A-transpose)

    Also for any matrix, H

      Rank(H) + dim( NullSpace(H) )  =  # of columns of H

    Therefore if H = A, which has # cols = n = 2, then 

       Rank(H)  + dim (NullSpace(H)) = 2
       1        + dim (NullSpace(H)) = 2
                  dim (NullSpace(H)) = 1


       since we set H to A,   
                  ->  dim (NullSpace(A)) = 1
                                                          (Result-1)

    Now set H = A-transpose, which has 3 columns.  Then:

      Rank(H)   + dim (NullSpace(H)) = 3
       1        + dim (NullSpace(H)) = 3
                  dim (NullSpace(H)) = 2

       since we set H to A-transpose,   
                  ->  dim (NullSpace(A-transpose)) = 2
                                                           (Result-2)
```

Combining Result-1 and Result-2, we get (in this case):

```
 dim (NullSpace(A)) = 1      !=   dim (NullSpace(A-transpose)) = 2
```

I'm guessing this applies for a all matrices (supposing the above reasoning is correct).. 
If I made a mistake, thanks in advance for pointing it out !

best regards
   - chris

Epilogue:  Got a great answer. Thanks, EuYu !   /chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct and it would be quite easy to convert your example into a proof for all such matrices.

From the rank-nullity theorem, we have
$$n = \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{null}(A)$$
Similarly, for the transpose we have
$$m = \mathrm{rank}\left(A^\mathrm{T}\right) + \mathrm{null}\left(A^\mathrm{T}\right) = \mathrm{rank}(A) + \mathrm{null}\left(A^\mathrm{T}\right)$$
This means that
$$\mathrm{null}(A) = n - \mathrm{rank}(A) \neq m - \mathrm{rank}(A) = \mathrm{null}\left(A^\mathrm{T}\right)$$
since $m\neq n$. In fact,  we have the two nullities equal if and only if $m=n$.